# Get date from weekday, month and year

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date

I have a column with the weekday, another with the month and another with the year. How do I get the actual date in python?

Comment: Please check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
It's also best to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to enable others to help you. 
And check [How to make pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? Show example data and expected result.

Comment: if you have `weekday` then you can't get one actual date because this `weekday` can gives 4 or 5 dates in every month. For example `monday, 10, 2022` gives dates `2022.10.03 (monday)`,  `2022.10.10 (monday)`, `2022.10.17 (monday)`, `2022.10.24 (monday)`, `2022.10.31 (monday)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"year": [2018], "month": [12], "day": [1]})

df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df[["year", "month", "day"]]).dt.date

print(df)
#    year  month  day        date
# 0  2018     12    1  2018-12-01
```

Comment: thanks for the help. But I have the day of the week instead of the specific day

Comment: What's the format? Like a string saying "Monday"? or an integer 3 indicating it's a Wednesday? Is there other information provided?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datetime library:

```py
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime(year, month, day)

print(x)
```

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: hanks for the help. But I have the day of the week instead of the specific day

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import date

print(date.today())
```

This should work!